# traversing an array one less time each time

Tags: matlab

Lets say I have an array of `[1,2,3,4,5]`

I want to attempt to traverse the array one less each time, while adding the numbers.

First time:

```
1+2+3+4+5 = 15
```

Second time:

```
2+3+4+5 = 14
```

Third time:

```
3+4+5 = 12
```

Fourth time:

```
4+5 = 9
```

Fifth time:

```
5 = 5
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you so much.
-AbysssCoder

Comment: Two nested loops.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: **Hint**: Sum the numbers in the array (let's call that `sum`). Iterate (loop over) the array from start to finish. Print the current `sum` and *then* subtract the value at the current position. For example, 15; then 15 - 1 = 14. Then 14 - 2 = 12 and so on.

Comment: hey thanks man. I am pretty proficient in java and know how to do it in java, I was just wondering if there were any other ways that were similar to MATLAB. and would working MATLAB

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged your question with MATLAB...

```matlab
>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]; % define array
>> cumsum(x, 'reverse') % cumulative sum in reverse order
ans =
    15    14    12     9     5
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought java would be similar but it's not at all lol. I know both languages though, but I just now realized you can't edit a for-loop variable in MATLAB.

Comment: @AbysssCoder You can, but it gets rewritten in the next iteration. [Example](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/Lb9IIVvBVsHQyphLAQhSMosLNLI1wWywuIE1inhqXsr//wA)

Answer (score -1):

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
        sum += arr[j];
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Something like this?

Comment: Hey thanks man. I am pretty proficient in java and know how to do it in java, I was just wondering if there were any other ways that were similar to MATLAB. and would working MATLAB

Comment: Please refrain from answering with only code. Instead, [edit] the question to explain why this code works. Either text around, or comments within the code are fine. Remember that you are not only answering to the OP, but also to any future readers.